# Is it true that for jordan block with zero eigenvalue we can choose basis where all diagonal elements are non zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Is it true that for jordan block with zero eigenvalue we can choose basis where all diagonal elements are non zero?
if there is a proper number 0, then you can try to find a matrix in the form of J^(-1) AJ (A is a matrix that has 0 on the diagonal and all 1 above it), so that it does not have zeros on the diagonal. I tried to write the inverse matrix through the matrix of algebraic complements, but nothing came of it.

Comment: This clearly isn't always possible, e.g. when $A$ is $1\times1$, or when $A$ is $n\times n$ for some odd $n$ and the field is $GF(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true, you have to find a nilpotent matrix represented in another base. For example the 2x2 matrix with the first row equal to (1,1) and the second equal (-1,-1). Call A this matrix and you get that A^2=0 , so  its eigenvalues are all 0 and the jordan form is with all zero in the diagonal and one 1. Obviously is not always possible.